# Spring Kafka batch within time window

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

Spring Boot environment listening to kafka topics(@KafkaListener / @StreamListener)
Configured the listener factory to operate in batch mode:

```
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory # setBatchListener
```

or via `application.properties`:

```
spring.kafka.listener.type=batch
```

How to configure the framework so that given two numbers: N and T, it will try to fetch N records for the listener but won't wait more than T seconds, like described here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/groupedWithin.html
Some properties I've looked at:

- `max-poll-records`  ensures one won't get more than N records in a batch
- `fetch-min-size` gets at least this amount of data in a fetch request
- `fetch-max-wait` but don't wait more than necessary
- `idleBetweenPolls` just sleep a bit between polls

It seems like `fetch-min-size` combined with `fetch-max-wait` should do it but they compare bytes, not messages/records.

It is obviously possible to implement that by hand, I'm looking whether it's possible to configure Spring to to that for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems like `fetch-min-size` combined with `fetch-max-wait` should do it but they compare bytes, not messages/records.

That is correct, unfortunately, Kafka provides no mechanism such as `fetch.min.records`.

I don't anticipate that Spring would layer this functionality on top of the kafka-clients; it would be better to ask for a new feature in Kafka itself.

Spring does not manipulate the records returned from the poll at all, except you can now specify `subBatchPerPartition` to get batches containing just one partition in order to properly support zombie fencing when using exactly once read/prcess/write.

Comment: Has it changed since 2019?

Comment: I am not aware of any such changes to the `kafka-clients`.